# jQuery .val() work but content then doesn't display

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a method that returns data from the database, then creates a string in the form of a html list tag

```
options.Append("<li value=\"" + reader["CIStatusID"].ToString() + "\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"filterOption checkable\">");
options.Append(reader["Status"].ToString() + "</a></li>");
```

then in my javascript i assign this to a ul tag named "filterType"

```
<div id="gearOptionsViewCaseFiles" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Filter by Status</a>
            <ul id="filterType">
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is how I populate my ul tag with the dynamically generated list items:

```
success: function (data) {
    $('#filterType').val('<li value="0" class="filterOption checkable checked"><a href="#">All<img class="checkedimage" src="Images/tick.png" width="12" height="12"></a></li>' + data);
}
```

in the debugger, the "filterType"'s value is the generated list items, but on the website, the list never appear. I can't seem to figure out why it is not displaying if it is assigning the generated html items to the "filterType" ul tag

**EDIT :**
what the li items looks like when it's being added to the ul:

```
<li value="0" class="filterOption checkable checked"><a href="#">All<img class="checkedimage" src="Images/tick.png" width="12" height="12"></a></li>
```

Comment: use `append()` or `html()` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#filterType').val()
```

Should be

```
$('#filterType').html()
```

`.val()` is for Form elements. The **ul** is not a form element.. So `.val()` will not work..

Use `.html()`

```
var html = '<li value="0" class="filterOption checkable checked"><a '  
            + 'href="#">All<img class="checkedimage" src="Images/tick.png" '  
            + ' width="12" height="12"></a></li>' + data;


$('#filterType').html(html);

OR 

document.getElementById('filterType').innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: thank you. I didn't know that. will mark as answer as soon as i can

Comment: actually, `.val()` isn't just for input type elements. Select boxes and textareas also work.

Comment: i'd usually use document.getElementById but jquery shortcuts seems slicker

Answer (score 3):

`.val` can only be used for form elements, AFAIK. Try using `.html` instead, like this:

```
$('#filterType').html('<li value="0" class="filterOption checkable checked"><a href="#">All<img class="checkedimage" src="Images/tick.png" width="12" height="12"></a></li>' + data);
```

A case in which you can use `.val()` is as the following:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="textbox" />
```

jQuery:

```
$("#textbox").val("foo"); // Assigns foo to the value of the textbox
```

Basically, `.val()` adds a `value` attribute to the selected element, which would modify the value of a form element, but do nothing with other elements.

**N.B.**: `.val()` is not the same as `.value` in JavaScript, as `.val()` works for textareas as well, and automatically uses `.innerText()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Use `.html` instead. Not `.val`

The `.val()` method is primarily used to get/set the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea